# Compressing a video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

I want to compress a video from the terminal using the  following:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf factor videocompressed.mp4
```

How do i specify where my video (video.mp4) is located? When I try to run this I get an error saying: video.mp4: No such file or directory

Comment: Is your terminal working directory contains the file `video.mp4`?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Have you also tried substituting an absolute path for the video input for the `-i` flag instead of using only the file name `video.mp4`?